# Delta load with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two Elasticsearch indexes say Index_A and Index_B. Index_A gets daily updates and inserts.
I need to do a delta loading on Index_B based on the data in Index_A on a weekly basis.

For Docy_Type =A, I should consider Modified Date and for Docy_Type =B, Created date should be considered.

My current indexes state:

[image]

So, after delta refresh, following conditions should be considered:

1. DocID 1 no update should happen in Index_B as there no change in Modified Date.
2. DocID 2 should be deleted from Index_B and new record from Index_A should be inserted as there is a change in Modified Date.
3. DocID 3 should be deleted from Index_B and new record from Index_A should be inserted as there is a change in Created Date.
4. DocID 4 no update should happen in Index_B as there no change in Created Date.
5. DocID 5 no update should happen in Index_B as there no change in Created Date.
6. DocID 6 should be inserted in Index_B as it is new/
7. DocID 7 should be deleted from Index_B as it is obselete.

So, my Index_B after Delta refresh:
[image]

Right now, my approach is to use Python scripting to achieve this.

Is there any other approach (apart from pythonic) with ES tools to handle such delta refresh? Thanks

Comment: You should look into transform https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transforms.html